# .Net Url Rewrite to another domain with a specific path pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a new site to replace one of my old site, and my purpose is to redirect some of the old site links to the backup server (I will keep the old site live for a period of time until I figured out all the url routings)

for example, here are some of the old links
https://www.example.com/category/something/here

I want my new site redirect the above urls to 
https://backup.example.com/category/something/here

I'm not good at Regex, I tried something like this but not working, any ideas? tks

```
    <rule name="Redirect URL" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)/category/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://backup.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: I will say you should not be doing a permanent redirect if it's only for a matter of time.

Comment: @RichardHubley - The OP said "I'm developing a new site to replace one of my old site". This implies that a permanent redirect is the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `url` can only match the path. To match the actual host name, you need to use `{HTTP_HOST}`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect www.example.com or example.com to backup.example.com" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^category/(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?example.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://backup.example.com/category/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>         
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpProtocol>
            <redirectHeaders>
                <!-- This is to ensure that clients don't cache the 301 itself - this is dangerous because the 301 can't change when put in place once it is cached -->
                <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache"/>
            </redirectHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also put in an example of how to turn off caching for 301 redirects. This can cause problems during debugging because browsers will cache the 301 redirect itself and then ignore any changes you make to this configuration unless the cache is cleared manually.

References:

- [Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS using the IIS URL Rewrite module](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/)
- [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Comment: tks for the reply, but event i take out the R:0 completely, just use url="https://backup.example.com", it still doesn't do redirect and give me 404 error on the new site

Comment: no, it still stays at www.example.com and since it's the new site, i got 404 error. Btw, the www and backup are hosted from two separate server

Comment: i'm using your second solution, match url="^http://www.example.com/category/(.*)"  .. but still don't get redirected to the backup domain

Comment: @JoeLu - I corrected the answer. Been awhile since I have done this and I forgot the host name is not part of the URL.

Comment: tks for the correction, good news is that I'm getting the redirection :) but the redirected url doesn't preserve "category" part, i.e. www.example.com/category/something/here got redirected to backup.example.com/something/here

Comment: also, if i add the httpProtocol part to the web.config, i got 500 error, I have to take it out, any idea? tks

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "httpProtocol part"?

Comment: never mind, i fixed it, it was the duplicated tag. So any idea about the missing "category" part? tks

Comment: @NightOwl888 I didn't know Chrome respected the no-cache of 301 redirects, which basically makes them treated like 302 redirects. Do you keep it a 301 for SSO reasons?

Comment: Yes, most browsers treat them the same. However, search engines transfer at least 90% of the "link juice" when you use a 301 and the link doesn't count for SEO if you use a 302. So if you want to move your site to a new location, 301 is definitely the way to go.